# Autoit - lost focus after child window pops up

Tags: autoit

I am trying to click on an item from combobox control from parent window.
once I click, a new child window pops up, then I need to click on OK button in the child window.

Problem here is, when the child window pops up, the autoit script loses its focus.
I have used WinGetTitle, WinWaitActive, WinActivate to get control of child window, but none are working.

Any help in this is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order for AutoIt to 'see' child windows, you need to set `Opt`

```
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
```

Comment: Thanks Milos, I tried this option, still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
$hGUI = GUICreate("Test", 500, 500)
$cButton = GUICtrlCreateButton("Child", 10, 10, 80, 30)
GUISetState()
While 1
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $cButton
            _Child()
    EndSwitch
WEnd
Func _Child()
    Global Const $hChild = GUICreate("Child", 200, 200)
    GUISetState()
    While 1
        Switch GUIGetMsg()
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                GUIDelete($hChild)
                Return
        EndSwitch
    WEnd
EndFunc
```